# identify a 128x64 LCD display

Tags: pic, identification, lcd

I am trying to identify an LCD display to get its datasheet. It will help to understand the assembly code of a PIC18F that uses it.

[image]

[image]

What I know of the display:

- the display is part of the [K8101 USB message display kit](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=410568) from Velleman
- 128x64 pixels oldschool grey lcd with white led backlight
- the only visible mark is a "A   WR60542801   K" that gives no result
- the display had no pcb (so it is a Chip-on-glass kind?) but a 30 pins connector that I soldered in the underlying pcb (and of course, I did not thought about noting any useful reference from the lower side - if any)
- the upper "display" pcb only helds 10 1µF ceramic capacitors and 1 1MΩ resistor and communicates with the lower pcb that hold the PIC (18F27J53) via a 18 pin connector. Seems to be in "8 parallel data lines" mode.
- while searching for the 30 pin connector, I found it could be driven by a [ST7565R](http://www.lcd-module.de/eng/pdf/zubehoer/st7565r.pdf) controller found on some other lcd boards, but the controller seems to be able to address 132x65 dots so am unsure of that
- the [board diagram](https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/0/illustrated/illustrated_assembly_manual_k8101.pdf) in the assembly manual does show a "ARROWTECH ATP12864WP67" name for the lcd, but searching for that name only retrieves... this assembly manual :(

I already dumped the PIC18 code, so having the display datasheet will help much.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably made by Xiamen Arrow-tech. (Xiamen is in Fujian province, near Taiwan and attracted a lot of investment from island-based entities early on).

As is typical in the semi-custom LCD business their web page shows only a small fraction of their products, but you may be able to figure out the controller from the disassembled code and the variety of controllers shown on [this](http://www.arrowtech.cn/product.asp?sort=2) page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to compare source code.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicslcddriv/

### updated

Note that you can verify the dimensions but I noted the clear corner plastic pc's and IO connector seem to be identical and is monochrome. Even if not the same , the functions will be similar.
[image]

Comment: This one has 28 pins vs 30 on the OP's display.

Comment: Oh well the functions of each signal can be matched up to resolve basic issues for assembly code.